# username and password asking while accessing http://servername/reports in ssrs 2014

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, rdl

I am using SQL server 2014.In RDL reports,when I am accessing http://servername/reports it asks a username and password. Where I get this username and password.. Or how can I skip this step?

Answer (score 0):

This prompt that you have specified is the authentication to the report server, by default RS uses windows authentication so enter your domain\username with password.

To bypass that you can check the Report Manager's web.config file for the `system.web` section and change the `authentication mode` as per your need OR you may check the UAC for your windows and disable it.

Below links for more details - 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253(v=sql.120).aspx
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249(v=sql.120).aspx